# Google OAuth denied in webapp when Safari was started via iOS homescreen

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, google-oauth, html

I developed a webapp which is accessing a user's Google Calendar and which was 
 working fine using Google's OAuth in the browser. But when a user puts it to his homescreen on iOS, it says something like "OAuth is no more supported in embedded browsers".
After searching the web I found out, this message is caused by Safari which reports a different user agent when opening it from homescreen.
But still I could not find any solution to that problem. Seems like I have to change the authentication completely to get it working.

Is there a way to "fix" Safari or is there a another authentication method? (Already saw Firebase, but I am not sure if it will work in for my situation).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift Can't you use that? Google's Sign-In SDK? and https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/ for Desktop browsers..

Comment: @Brandon I didn't mention yet, that I am gonna to access a user's calendar. Since it is a webapp Swift won't work. Could not find any information about Identity Sign-in, if it can grant me calendar access.